# Is there a function to calculate returns?

Tags: excel, finance, worksheet

I am trying to calculate returns for a security in the following way. A signal, e.g. "BUY", goes on for several periods until a new signal, e.g. "SELL", is generated. For example, supposing the Buy signal starts in period 1 and goes on until period 5, the return would be (price_t_5 / price_t_1 - 1) as usual -- see the

[image].

Is there an Excel function to calculate this easily? 
Thank you!

Comment: The quickest way would be to fill the gaps in the signal column first.

Comment: But to obtain the returns (last column on the rhs), I would need the first price and the last one before the signal changes again. How do I put this into an Excel code?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I've tried several things but none seems to be working (eg linking returns based on signal etc.). I just cannot think of any other way of doing this on Excel in a straightforward manner.

Comment: You can use special cells - blanks to fill the gaps quickly. Post what you've tried so that we might be able to suggest changes.

Comment: Do you need an Excel-native group of functions or a manually written function will be fine too?

Comment: I'd rather an Excel-native group of functions. But a manually written one will be okay.

Comment: Do you guys have any suggestion?